# linq select within where clause

Tags: c#, linq

i have a class and a collection with in it.

```
class A
{
B[] boxes;
}

class B
{
string boxNumber;
}
```

Now, i need to create an object of type A that internally has B[] with only even box numbers.
can anyone help me with the linq query?

Comment: why is `boxNumber` a string? Looks like it should be an umber

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This query should give you the boxes with even box numbers from a given A:

```
A myA = new A();

IEnumerable<B> BsWithEvenBoxNumbers = myA.boxes.Where(b => Int32.Parse(b.boxNumber) % 2 == 0);
```

Or, if you want the result in array form:

```
B[] BsWithEvenBoxNumbersArr = myA.boxes.Where(b => Int32.Parse(b.boxNumber) % 2 == 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Probably need to add ToArray()